# ¿Solucionar problema con column-gap en css grid?

Tags: html5, css3

Buenas tengo un problema usando css grid, al tratar de dar un column gap este se sale del tamaño de pantalla que tengo es decir aparece el scroll horizontal, tengo esto en el css

```
 .container{
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  column-gap: 10px;

 }

.banner-med{
height: 500px;
background-color: salmon;
}
```

estos son 2 div pero al dar separación no respeta el ancho de pantalla no se si se puede solucionar o que me recomiendan

Answer (score 0):

ya esta resuelto, cambie la unidad de medida en:

```
   grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
```

por:

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: De hecho con poner `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` alcanza, por cierto para la próxima trata de incluir además el HTML para tener un código completo donde ver el problema expuesto